# Accessing inner class methods on already created outer class object

Tags: java, inner-classes, nested-class

Let's say I have class like this:

```
class Outer { 
   public void getOuterValue() { } 

   class Inner { 
       public void getInnerValue() { }
   } 
}
```

I understand that I could create an object of this class as:

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
```

But let's suppose I am getting this object from some other method:

```
void someMethodSomewhere(Outer o) { 
        // How do I call getInnerValue() here using o? 
}
```

Is there a way to call "getInnerValue" method using "o" in the scenario above?

Please let me know.

Comment: I tried "o.getInnerValue()" it did not work unfortunately.

Comment: @LutzHorn Nope you cant do that. Inner is a member instance that requires an instance of Outer, hence outer.new Inner, rather than new Outer.Inner()

Comment: @Lutz Horn No, it can't work! There might be an arbitrary number of objects of type `Inner`, so it can't even work in theory.

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to have an instance of `Inner` to call methods on it.

An instance of the outer class is not enough (it would work the other way around: the inner class instance has a reference to the outer class instance).

Comment: I see. So, I guess, I would have to get rid of inner class and have method on outerclass.

Comment: Or pass in an instance of `Inner`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void someMethodSomewhere(Outer o) { 
    // How do I call getInnerValue() here using o? 
}
```

You can't.  getInnerValue() is a method in Inner.  Outer is not an Inner and does not have a reference to an Inner.  When you are handed `o`, there is no way to navigate from that to any instance of Inner because there isn't one associated with `o`.

Comment: Is there a way to associate it with "o"? I guess, I could keep an instance of "Inner" in "Outer"

Comment: If `o` had an instance of Inner, then yes of course.  That would be no different than `o` have an instance of a StringBuffer or an ArrayList or anything else.  The code as written in the description does not include any instance of Inner belonging to or reachable from `o`.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping not to keep that instance that's why I didn't include that in the description. Thanks for the explanation!